# Is there any way to get only the unnamed arguments?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

In JavaScript functions, [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) is an array-like object containing all arguments to the function, whether they are named or not:

```
function f(foo, bar) {
    console.log(arguments);
}
f(1, '2', 'foo'); // [1, "2", "foo"]
```

Is there a way to get *only* the arguments that are not named, so you could do something like this?

```
function f(foo, bar) {
    console.log('foo:', foo, 'bar:', bar, 'the rest:', unnamedArguments);
}
f(1, '2', 'foo'); // foo: 1 bar: "2" the rest: ["foo"]
```

### But why?

A real-world use case is for injecting Angular modules as arguments into RequireJS modules:

```
define([
    'angular',
    'myLibModule', // Exports an Angular module object
    'myOtherLibModule', // Exports an Angular module object
], function(angular, myLibModule, myOtherLibModule) {
    angular.module('MyApp', [myLibModule.name, myOtherLibModule.name]);
});
```

As the list of module dependencies can get quite large, this quickly becomes very cumbersome. While I could solve it as

```
define([
    'angular',
    'underscore',
    'myLibModule', // Exports an Angular module object
    'myOtherLibModule', // Exports an Angular module object
], function(angular, _) {
    function angularModuleNames(modules) {
        return _.pluck(_.pick(modules, function(item) {
            return _.has(item, 'name');
        }), 'name');
    }
    angular.module('MyApp', angularModuleNames(arguments));
});
```

this is also rather cumbersome, and it would be nice if I could do something like this instead:

```
define([
    'angular',
    'underscore',
    'myLibModule', // Exports an Angular module object
    'myOtherLibModule', // Exports an Angular module object
], function(angular, _) {
    angular.module('MyApp', _.pluck(unnamedArguments, 'name'));
});
```

Of course, a way to group dependencies in RequireJS would suffice just as well for this particular use case.

Comment: The ES6 feature of [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/rest_parameters) (as in "...and the rest of the arguments") does exactly what you describe in your question, but it is not yet widely implemented. With that feature, you could define `function f(foo, bar, ...unnamedArguments)`.

Comment: Indeed. Python and Java (and probably lots of other languages) have had the feature for a long time, so it would be nice to see it come to JS as well.

Comment: @EmilLundberg TBH it's already easy to make variadic functions in ES5,  even without the function length : you most often *know* the number of declared arguments of your function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The number of declared arguments is provided in the `length` property of the function.

So you can get the arguments whose index is greater or equal to this `length` :

```
var undeclaredArgs = [].slice.call(arguments, arguments.callee.length);
```

As [you can't use `arguments.callee` in strict mode starting from ES5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee#Why_was_arguments.callee_removed_from_ES5_strict_mode.3F), you should use a reference to the function whenever possible :

```
var undeclaredArgs = [].slice.call(arguments, f.length);
```

Comment: +1. Never use `arguments.callee`, just name the function expression.

Comment: Perfect! So `define([ ... ], function module(angular, _) { ... })` and `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, module.length)` is the way to go then.

Comment: @Bergi—but noting the issues with [*named function expressions in IE*](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/#jscript-bugs), so better to use function declarations.

Comment: @RobG: Yeah, I know about them, but I tend to ignore oldIE. By the nature of the bug, it might leak some function objects, but most code still works as expected.